# What is the difference between src="/images/logo.gif" and src="images/logo.gif"?

Tags: html

```
<img src="images/logo.gif" />
```

is equivalent to

```
<img src="./images/logo.gif" />
```

But

```
<img src="/images/logo.gif" />
```

is different.

Where is the third item looking for logo.gif?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

***images/logo.gif***

It's relative and means: Go to a folder called *images* and then get the resource *logo.gif*

***./images/logo.gif***

It's relative and means: From the current folder (the dot means this) go to a folder called *images* and then get the resource *logo.gif*

As you can see the first two mean the same, finally the last one

***/images/logo.gif***

It's absolute and means: From the root of the web server or the file system or whatever (the slash means this) go to a folder called *images* and then get the resource *logo.gif*

Comment: But not AS absolute as http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif would be. I like to think of it as relatively absolute :)

Comment: In what case would they differ? say if you were using a mod_rewrite or sub directory?

Comment: oops - my comment above should have the full protocol at the beginning - damn autolinking! They would differ if you moved from one domain (or sub-domain) to another; not a common occurrence, but there's still an air of 'relativity' about /images.

Answer (score 10):

The third one is looking relative to the root of the site, so if you were on a page at:

```
http://entrian.com/somewhere/page.html
```

it would look in:

```
http://entrian.com/images/logo.gif
```

ignoring the `somewhere` piece of the page's address.

Comment: What if the .html file is on your local disk though?

Comment: On the local disk, it goes back to the root of the drive; E:\somewhere\page.html -> E:\images\logo.gif on windows, /home/me/somewhere/page.html -> /images/logo.gif on unix.

Comment: @bobobobo: It will look for the file at /images/logo.gif on your local machine. On Unix that'll be fine; on Windows it might work depending on your browser (it will work in IE, but not in Firefox). Depending on the browser, you might have to explicitly say href="file://c:/images/logo.gif". If you're writing the page for the web, but testing on your local machine, you should install a web server and test under that - loading it directly from the file system is not a realistic test of how the page will load under a real web server.

Answer (score 0):

In the document root. The first two are relative paths, while the last is an absolute path.