# How to use <base /> to redirect links?

Tags: html

I have an info page I've written in plain HTML.

All the image links are like so:

<img src="/images/image.png" /> so that [they refer to the root of the web site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1140755/what-is-the-difference-between-src-images-logo-gif-and-srcimages-logo-gif).

However I want to look at the page with the images embedded before updating it.  In chrome, <img src="/images/image.png" /> looks in file:///c:/imgs/.  However I want to redirect this to file:///C:/web/site/imgs/.

I'm trying to use [<base >](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_base.asp) to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `<base>` when your URLs are absolute like that.  Here are a couple of alternatives:

**Solution #1:** Use the Windows `subst` command to make a drive letter for your "root" directory:

```
subst R: C:\web\site
```

then point your browser at R:\

**Solution #2:** Install a web server with the root configured to be `C:\web\site`, and point your browser at that.

Using a real web server is a much better way to test a web site - things like the browser's JavaScript security policies are significantly different between local files and files read via a web server.

Answer (score 2):

`<base >` only affects page-relative links.  It essentially "pretends" your page is in a different location, so addresses given relative to the page will now be relative to that new location.

Your addresses aren't relative to the page at all.  Regardless of where within `file:///` you say the page is, the images are quite clearly given as "/images/..."

On most platforms, setting up a simple web server on localhost is fairly straightforward.  (Mac OS X comes with one out of the box, which requires nothing more than checking a box in System Preferences.)  Setting up such a server for development would let you view the site at http://localhost/ and might resolve this "relative links" problem.

If that solution is impractical, you might consider setting up aliases or symlinks to make the server-relative links that you already have work correctly.  That's a bit hackish, though.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to change the image paths to relative URLs if you want the < BASE > tag to change the domain as well as the folder path.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you must be sure that the base's href property content ends with `/`

for example:

```
<base href="file:///C:/web/site/imgs/" />
```

given that, base will change the behaviour of all the **relative** URIs in your page, so `<img src="/images/image.png" />` will continue to point to `file:///images/image.png`, but

```
<img src="images/image.png" />
```

will now point to `file:///C:/web/site/imgs/images/image.png` .