# Difference between "./images/pic.png" and "images/pic.png"?

Tags: html

Hello I recently stumbled upon something that I think has to do with formality. I have always used this to refer to files like this:

```
<img src="images/cute_cat.png" />
```

However I recently saw people using this instead:

```
<img src="./images/cute_cat.png" />
```

My question is if there's any logical explanation or if it's just a formality thing that some like to use and some don't.

Comment: oh no, now we'll have cats on SO as well?

Comment: http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/img/src

Comment: @KarolyHorvath why not? this answers the question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1140765/1266600

Comment: @Jawad: not relevant.

Comment: @sushain97: I find it confusing to close it with a different question, even though one of the answers addresses it... the fact that not the accepted answer does this makes it even worse.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath nope, they'd have to beat the unicorns.

Comment: @Tom: that's going to be an epic battle

Comment: Yeah I think I got all the information I needed and I thank you all for that. Now I'm just waiting to close the question by accepting an answer (cool down period thing).

Comment: @KarolyHorvath, true. However, the linked answer is (arguably) better than the current answer. What's the convention in such a situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./` means the same directory.
`../` means parent directory.
`/` means the first directory of that domain.

In your case, they mean the same thing.